# Extract firmware from STM32F030 using ST-Link clone

Tags: firmware

I have a Finger pulse oximeter and inside I found a STM32F030C8T6 MCU.
I'm looking to replace the firmware with one of my own.

Is it possible to dump the current firmware and restore it, perhaps even to another dev board running the exact same cpu?

Exposed pins: TX, RX, GND, VBAT, 3.3V

I have a ST-Link V2 clone and am familiar with uploading new firmware, just not downloading existing.

To upload new firmware, I run:

```
st-util
arm-none-eabi-gdb new_firmware.elf
(gdb) target extended localhost:4242
(gdb) load
```

Not sure what the process is to download existing though. Little help?

Photos of the board:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/74ouV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycmbU.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the datasheet for the chip and try tracing the JTAG/SWD pins. Possibly some of them are routed to the unlabeled 7-pin pad at the top. To dump the firmware you can probably just use the [`dump` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html) (see the datasheet for memory ranges)